# How to use Group By with Join table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When execute my query , I get error message like below.

```
$ads = DB::table('ads')
        ->join('adimages','adimages.ad_id','=','ads.id')
        ->select(
            'adimages.ad_id',
            'ads.ad_title',
            'ads.created_at',
            'ads.beds',
            'ads.baths',
            'ads.landmark',
            'ads.city',
            'ads.price',
            'adimages.photo'
        )
        ->groupBy('adimages.ad_id')
        ->get();
```

Here is the error I'm getting.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'nekton.ads.ad_title' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `adimages`.`ad_id`, `ads`.`ad_title`, `ads`.`created_at`, `ads`.`beds`, `ads`.`baths`, `ads`.`landmark`, `ads`.`city`, `ads`.`price`, `adimages`.`photo` from `ads` inner join `adimages` on `adimages`.`ad_id` = `ads`.`id` group by `adimages`.`ad_id`)

Comment: Where `nekton.ads.ad_title` is came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel, you need to disable strict key in `database.php` file. Please follow below steps

```
1. Open config/database.php
2. Find strict key inside mysql connection settings
3. Set the value to false
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: While setting `"strict" => false` in the Laravel config will disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` which appears to be the cause of the issue. Doing so will result in unexpected results by the improper use of `GROUP BY` statements, as [MySQL is free to choose any value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) from the columns that are not in the grouped data set. Another alternative is to use `SELECT ANY_VALUE(ads.ad_title) AS ad_title`.